# redirect to error page when status of response is 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, response, react-router-dom

I want to redirect to other page when I get status code (404) from response. I don't know how I can done it.

```
export function requestOperator() {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return api
            .requestOperator()
            .then(async response => {
                await dispatch(setRequestOperator(response));
                await dispatch(setSelectedRequest(response));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                Promise.reject(error);

            })
    }
}
```